# How to get the token from the api response (react-native)

Tags: android, react-native, token, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I want to call the rest API of text to speach service by react-native. When I want to get the token of my service, I don't know which part of the response I need to use.

This is the response details:
[image]

What's more, what is the response format of text to speech API? I want to save the audio in react-native but have no idea about this.

Comment: You expanded header part. Check body part of the response.

Comment: The header part just has a field called 'map'

Comment: Maybe the `url` property from the response and use that to issue a token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that the fetch function of react-native can not return the body of API response directly. So, the workround is below:

> fetch('https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken', {
>               method: 'POST',
>               headers: {
>                   'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey,
>                   'Content-Length': '0',
>                   'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
>               }
>           }).then((response) =>{
>               return  response.text();
>           })
>               .then((response) => {
>               let test= response;
>           })